# Strip off empty root element only

Tags: xml, xslt, strip

I have a Input XML which looks like this and want the desired output as shown below using XSL transformation.  I've been looking through the blog but couldn't find any relevance on how to remove empty tags matching the root element only not the child nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
  <Revenue__c/>
  <Revenue__c/>
  <Revenue__c/>
  <Revenue__c>
    <Sales_Org_ID__c>IV</Sales_Org_ID__c>
    <Branch_ID__c>1</Branch_ID__c>
    <Branch_Name__c>TEST</Branch_Name__c>
    <Therapy_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Code__c>
    <Therapy_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Name__c>
    <Therapy_Class_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Code__c>
    <Therapy_Class_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Name__c>
    <Payor_Type_Name__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Name__c>
    <Calendar_Year_Number__c>2011</Calendar_Year_Number__c>
    <Month_Revenue_Amount__c>100.01</Month_Revenue_Amount__c>
    <Payor_ID__c>TEST</Payor_ID__c>
    <Payor_Name__c/>
    <Payor_Type_Code__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Code__c>
    <MDM_Account_EID__c>66600001</MDM_Account_EID__c>
    <MDM_Physician_EID__c>99900001</MDM_Physician_EID__c>
    <Account__c>001a000001APU5OAAX</Account__c>
    <Contact__c>003a000001RL1EFAA1</Contact__c>
    <Revenue_ID__c>41</Revenue_ID__c>
    <Calendar_Year_Month__c>01</Calendar_Year_Month__c>
  </Revenue__c>
</objects>
```

This is exactly the out that I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
  <Revenue__c>
    <Sales_Org_ID__c>IV</Sales_Org_ID__c>
    <Branch_ID__c>1</Branch_ID__c>
    <Branch_Name__c>TEST</Branch_Name__c>
    <Therapy_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Code__c>
    <Therapy_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Name__c>
    <Therapy_Class_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Code__c>
    <Therapy_Class_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Name__c>
    <Payor_Type_Name__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Name__c>
    <Calendar_Year_Number__c>2011</Calendar_Year_Number__c>
    <Month_Revenue_Amount__c>100.01</Month_Revenue_Amount__c>
    <Payor_ID__c>TEST</Payor_ID__c>
    <Payor_Name__c/>
    <Payor_Type_Code__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Code__c>
    <MDM_Account_EID__c>66600001</MDM_Account_EID__c>
    <MDM_Physician_EID__c>99900001</MDM_Physician_EID__c>
    <Account__c>001a000001APU5OAAX</Account__c>
    <Contact__c>003a000001RL1EFAA1</Contact__c>
    <Revenue_ID__c>41</Revenue_ID__c>
    <Calendar_Year_Month__c>01</Calendar_Year_Month__c>
  </Revenue__c>
</objects>
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Point of clarification ... the empty `<Revenue__c/>` elements are not "root elements". "Root" refers to the outermost level of the document. The `<Revenue_c/>` elements have a parent, `<object>`, so they cannot be roots.

Comment: Oh, maybe you meant "leaf elements", that is, elements that have no children. ("Leaf node" is a common term in graph theory and CS, but not in XML in particular, unlike "root node".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it - it uses `apply-templates` only to Revenue nodes with children, and then `copy-of` to copy the non empty Revenue trees.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:x="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com"
                exclude-result-prefixes="x">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/x:objects">
    <objects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="x:Revenue__c[*]" />
    </objects>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x:Revenue__c">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
  <Revenue__c>
    <Sales_Org_ID__c>IV</Sales_Org_ID__c>
    <Branch_ID__c>1</Branch_ID__c>
    <Branch_Name__c>TEST</Branch_Name__c>
    <Therapy_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Code__c>
    <Therapy_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Name__c>
    <Therapy_Class_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Code__c>
    <Therapy_Class_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Name__c>
    <Payor_Type_Name__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Name__c>
    <Calendar_Year_Number__c>2011</Calendar_Year_Number__c>
    <Month_Revenue_Amount__c>100.01</Month_Revenue_Amount__c>
    <Payor_ID__c>TEST</Payor_ID__c>
    <Payor_Name__c />
    <Payor_Type_Code__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Code__c>
    <MDM_Account_EID__c>66600001</MDM_Account_EID__c>
    <MDM_Physician_EID__c>99900001</MDM_Physician_EID__c>
    <Account__c>001a000001APU5OAAX</Account__c>
    <Contact__c>003a000001RL1EFAA1</Contact__c>
    <Revenue_ID__c>41</Revenue_ID__c>
    <Calendar_Year_Month__c>01</Calendar_Year_Month__c>
  </Revenue__c>
</objects>
```

**Edit** - It can be simplified:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:x="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com"
                exclude-result-prefixes="x">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/x:objects">
    <objects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
      <xsl:copy-of select="x:Revenue__c[*]" />
    </objects>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 5):

**This is probably the simplest/shortest solution that at the same time is completely "push style" and is most extensible and maintainable -- no hardcoded element names, no literal result elements, no namespaces, no `xsl:copy-of`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(node())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<objects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <Revenue__c/>
    <Revenue__c/>
    <Revenue__c/>
    <Revenue__c>
        <Sales_Org_ID__c>IV</Sales_Org_ID__c>
        <Branch_ID__c>1</Branch_ID__c>
        <Branch_Name__c>TEST</Branch_Name__c>
        <Therapy_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Code__c>
        <Therapy_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Name__c>
        <Therapy_Class_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Code__c>
        <Therapy_Class_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Name__c>
        <Payor_Type_Name__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Name__c>
        <Calendar_Year_Number__c>2011</Calendar_Year_Number__c>
        <Month_Revenue_Amount__c>100.01</Month_Revenue_Amount__c>
        <Payor_ID__c>TEST</Payor_ID__c>
        <Payor_Name__c/>
        <Payor_Type_Code__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Code__c>
        <MDM_Account_EID__c>66600001</MDM_Account_EID__c>
        <MDM_Physician_EID__c>99900001</MDM_Physician_EID__c>
        <Account__c>001a000001APU5OAAX</Account__c>
        <Contact__c>003a000001RL1EFAA1</Contact__c>
        <Revenue_ID__c>41</Revenue_ID__c>
        <Calendar_Year_Month__c>01</Calendar_Year_Month__c>
    </Revenue__c>
</objects>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<objects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <Revenue__c>
      <Sales_Org_ID__c>IV</Sales_Org_ID__c>
      <Branch_ID__c>1</Branch_ID__c>
      <Branch_Name__c>TEST</Branch_Name__c>
      <Therapy_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Code__c>
      <Therapy_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Name__c>
      <Therapy_Class_Code__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Code__c>
      <Therapy_Class_Name__c>TEST</Therapy_Class_Name__c>
      <Payor_Type_Name__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Name__c>
      <Calendar_Year_Number__c>2011</Calendar_Year_Number__c>
      <Month_Revenue_Amount__c>100.01</Month_Revenue_Amount__c>
      <Payor_ID__c>TEST</Payor_ID__c>
      <Payor_Name__c/>
      <Payor_Type_Code__c>TEST</Payor_Type_Code__c>
      <MDM_Account_EID__c>66600001</MDM_Account_EID__c>
      <MDM_Physician_EID__c>99900001</MDM_Physician_EID__c>
      <Account__c>001a000001APU5OAAX</Account__c>
      <Contact__c>003a000001RL1EFAA1</Contact__c>
      <Revenue_ID__c>41</Revenue_ID__c>
      <Calendar_Year_Month__c>01</Calendar_Year_Month__c>
   </Revenue__c>
</objects>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies "as-is" any node for which this template is selected for execution.
2. There is a single template overriding the identity template for any element that is a child of the top element and that has no children. This template has no body (doesn't produce any output), which effectively "deletes" the matched node.

Comment: +1, good solution. For completeness, we might point out that the `<xsl:template match="/*/*[not(node())]"/>` template will swallow elements that have attributes (but no children). Maybe that's what the OP wants, if "empty" just means "no children". This doesn't matter with the given input data, anyway. But if we decide we don't want to swallow elements that have attributes: `<xsl:template match="/*/*[not(node()|@*)]"/>`

Comment: @LarsH, Yes, that is correct. This solution targets just the provided XML document. Thanks.